# Keeping proper column widths in a table inside a modal with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I keep the rows and lines in the table below from extending past the boarder of the `modal-content` class?

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">This is my model</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="my_table" class="table-responsive filterable TF" width="auto">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td><a href="/1">Paaaa</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="/2">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.model-content {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use;

```
#my_table td a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

to break line.

Comment: This is CSS3 only, which may be the problem

Comment: @pyCthon did you checked adding it on a tag? -jeremy it has fairly good support in latest browsers. check here for more http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Comment: Ya you're right, and this is the right answer, just OP originally said it didn't work which made me think that may have been the problem.